# Riemann Zeta - limits when $ζ(1-s)=0$ when $s= 1/2 +it$ (zeta zero).

Tags: limits, riemann-zeta

Consider the following integral of the Riemann zeta function
$$
\zeta ( s) \Gamma ( s) =\ \int _{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x} -1} dx.
$$
Through substitution, this integral becomes the following:$$
\zeta ( s) \Gamma ( s) =\ \int _{0}^{1}\frac{\ ( -\ln( 1-u))^{s-1}}{u} du .
$$
Remembering that
$$
\ln( 1-x) \ =\ -\left( \ x+\frac{x^{2}}{2} +\frac{x^{3}}{3} +\ldots\right)
$$
Therefore solving this integral we obtain the following:

$$ζ(s)Γ(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s-1}{2s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a(n,k)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k}(s-j)\right)\right) .$$

Using the properties of the gamma function and the zeta reflection equation :

$$ζ(s)=2^{s}π^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)ζ(1-s)Γ(1-s). $$

We therefore obtain the following:

$$ ζ(1-s)=2^{s}π^{s-1}\cos\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)(\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s-1}{2s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a(n,k)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k}(s-j)\right)\right))$$

Lets call

$$ f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a(n,k)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k}(s-j)\right)\right).$$

Therefore $$ζ(1-s) =2^{-s+1}π^{-s} \cos\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s-1}{2s} + f(s)\right).$$
Let us call $X(s) = 2^{-s+1}π^{-s} \cos(\frac{πs}{2})$,
therefore $ζ(1-s) =X(s)(\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s-1}{2s} + f(s))$.

Let us consider the case where $s= a+it$, therefore considering $ζ(1-s)=0$
and substituting $a=\frac{1}{2}$  in the following: $f(s)=-(\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{s-1}{2s} )$,

$$ f\left(\frac{1}{2}+it\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{5-4t^{2}}{1+4t^{2}}\right)+i\left(\frac{2t}{1+4t^{2}}\right) .$$

But if the actual equation for $f(s)$ is the following:

$$ f(s) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(s+n)}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} a(n,k)\left(\prod_{j=1}^{k}(s-j)\right)\right).$$

Therefore my question is how can we prove that this infinite sum above goes to the same limit?

**Note 1:** this seems to be a polynomial of infinite order therefore this may be violating some theorem I am not aware of?

**Note 2:** here below are a few terms of $f(s)$, I have also found the general term of how to calculate the $a(n,k)$ values but have not included here.
\begin{align*}
f(s)=&\; \frac{1}{s+1}\left( \frac{1}{3}(s-1)+\frac{1}{8}(s-1)(s-2)\right)\\
 &+ \frac{1}{s+2}\left( \frac{1}{4}(s-1)+ \frac{1}{6}(s-1)(s-2)+ \frac{1}{48}(s-1)(s-2)(s-3)\right)\\
&+ \frac{1}{s+3}\left( \frac{1}{5}(s-1)+ \frac{13}{72}(s-1)(s-2)+ \frac{1}{24}(s-1)(s-2)(s-3)\right. \\ &  +\left. \frac{1}{384}(s-1)(s-2)(s-3)(s-4)\right) + \ldots \,.
\end{align*}

Comment: Please do not write the text in math mode.

Comment: thanks Gary, this was my first post will remember for the next time.

Comment: Gary thanks for editing my question

Comment: When you use the symmetry relation for the zeta, $2^{s}π^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)$ should multiply the whole thing not just $\frac{1}{s-1}$, right? Also, how did $2^{s}π^{s-1}\sin\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)$ become $2^{-s+1}π^{-s}\cos\left(\frac{πs}{2}\right)$? Also $\zeta(1-s)=0$ happens for certain values of $t$. What does $t\to \infty$ mean? Are you approaching infinity along the non-trivial zeros?

Comment: hi Gary, yes of course the 2^s π^s−1sin(πs/2) should multiply the whole thing that's a typo and with your second point I think you actually answered my question because at a non trivial zero yes ζ(1−s)=0 but I guess I can't hold this to be true and then let t-> infinity at the same time because the non-trivial zeros explicitly mean that  ζ(1−s)=0 at a specific value of t.  therefore both the question and thesis are misleading.  2sπs−1sin(πs2) became 2^−s+1 π^−s cos(πs2)  through the property of the Gamma function and some trigonometric manipulation.

Comment: Gary me again, the 2^s π^s−1sin(πs/2)  should be 2^s π^s−1cos(πs/2)

Comment: I think that this question can be salvaged by asking if f(s) goes to the same limit as for example at a zeta zero

Comment: Gary take a look at the question title and the body itself i think it makes more sense now I just took out the limit at t-> infinity which really had no sense in my view but let me know what you think? ciao